# Is SUBSET SUM only for positive integers in P or NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, np, subset-sum

Since UNARY SUBSET SUM is in P, and a positive-only SUBSET SUM problem could be represented in unary, I struggle to see why it wouldn't be the case that it is in P, when restricted to positive numbers?

Comment: did you mean that if the input encoding with unary alphabet then subset-sum in P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subset-sum is not in $P$ for a Positive Integer, The reason that subset-sum in P for an unary alphabet is that Subset-sum admit a pseudo-polynomial algorithm, and the running time of the algorithm is measured with respect to the length of the input, the length of the encoding of an integer is $log_b(n)$ where $b$ is the base that using, but if $b = 1 $ then the length of the integer is $|n|$ in that case the pseudo-polynomial algorithm is a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: I think I understand, since there's no function that can go from base b to base 1 in polynomial time, you can't reduce Subset-sum on positive integers to Unary Subset-sum.

Comment: You can think about that way